# What if I want to use ViewPager with support.v4.app?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

The ViewPager is included in support library, all the methods of it require a parameter or a return of Fragment from support.v4.app, so I have to make sure all my fragments to extend support.v4.app.Fragment.

Can I use android.app.Fragmnet instead of support.v4.app.Fragment and how? Or how can I replace ViewPager?

Comment: I suppose they can't be merged. If you need backward compatibility, you should use the fragment and viewpager in support library. Otherwise, you can use the normal ones.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can: `ViewPager` is from `android.support.v4` library, but you can use `Adapters` from `android.support.v13` library to create its fragments.

`FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` from `android.support.v4` use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

But `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` from `android.support.v13` **use regular `android.app.Fragment`.**

[android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)
[android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to use support.v4.app.Fragment if you're using the support library's ViewPager.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html, if using `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`, you also have to use  `support.v4.app.Fragment`.